# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to show data from a JSON object in the content section of a WordPress website. The following static HTML works like a charm.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Now Playing</title>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function radioTitle() {

// this is the URL of the json.xml file located on your server.
            var url = 'http://my.radio.fm:8000/json.xsl';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                async: true,
                jsonpCallback: 'parseMusic',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json) {
                    // this is the element we're updating that will hold the track title
                    $('#track-title').text(json['/128k.mp3']['title']);
                    // this is the element we're updating that will hold the listeners count
                    $('#listeners').text(json['/128k.mp3']['listeners']);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });

        }

        $(document).ready(function(){

            setTimeout(function(){radioTitle();}, 2000);
            setInterval(function(){radioTitle();}, 15000); // we're going to update our html elements / player every 15 seconds

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Listeners: <span id="listeners">00</span></p>
<p>Now Playing: <span id="track-title">LIVE</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I put the JavaScript (without jQuery) into a separate file and wp_enqueue_script it in my functions.php like so

```
function kirtan_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'kirtan-nowplaying', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/nowplaying.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kirtan_scripts' );
```

it logs the following error to the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined radioTitle  
(anonymous function)
```

Why is it undefined when I use it in a separate JavaScript file and not undefined when I put it inline into the HTML head?

Comment: I suppose you know about [jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). Aside from that, on a technical note, you probably should always show the not working code.

Comment: Lets see the relevant code in functions.php. Chiefly - are you setting jQuery as a dependency on your enqueue?

Comment: Thanks @ialocin for the pointer, I came across that already, but have to admit that my jQuery and JavaScript is pretty poor. The not working code that I put in an external nowplaying.js is inside the `<script type="text/javascript">` tag, so I'm not sure what exactly to modify in order to make it compatible with noConflict mode.

Comment: @vancoder I tried that yesterday, too, but jQuery is already enqueued by the parent theme, so I thought it was not necessary.

Comment: So we know now where problem lies...read the resource I linked...in a nutshell, you can't use $ the way you have it now.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588941/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-ajax-of-undefined